# How to sum two arrays data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I sum data of my first array with data of array in it?

[image: one]

## code

this is my current code which is working on first array only

```
calculateTotal: function(){
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0;i<this.accounts.length;i++){
     sum += this.accounts[i].balance;
  }
  return sum;
},
```

What should I change in this code to get the result i want?

Comment: Please post the source object as text instead

Comment: Can you please if `this.accounts` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
 calculateTotal: function(){
      var sum=0;
      for(var i=0;i<this.accounts.length;i++){
         sum += this.accounts[i].balance;
         // iterate over payments sub array in each account and add balance into the sum
         for(var j=0;j<this.accounts[i].payments.length;j++){
             sum += this.accounts[i].payments[j].balance;
         }
      }
      return sum;
    },
```

Comment: need 10 min time before i be able to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need not only the `balance` property, but you also need to add every `balance` property in the `payments` array. You can do this very concisely with `reduce`, passing in the outer `balance` as the initial value of the accumulator:

```js
const obj = {
  accounts: [{
    balance: 150000,
    payments: [{
        balance: 100000,
      },
      {
        balance: -200000,
      }
    ]
  }]
};
const total = obj.accounts.reduce((a, { balance, payments }) => (
  a + payments.reduce((accum, { balance }) => accum + balance, balance)
), 0);
console.log(total);
```

Or, in object method form:

```js
const obj = {
  calculateTotal() {
    return obj.accounts.reduce((a, { balance, payments }) => (
      a + payments.reduce((accum, { balance }) => accum + balance, balance)
    ), 0)
  },
  accounts: [{
    balance: 150000,
    payments: [{
        balance: 100000,
      },
      {
        balance: -200000,
      }
    ]
  }]
};
console.log(obj.calculateTotal());
```

Comment: `const total = obj.accounts.reduce((a, { balance, payments }) => (
  a + payments.reduce((accum, { balance }) => accum + balance, balance)
), 0);` how can I use this part in my code? PS: I'm using vue.js and my code is placed in `methods: {...}`

Comment: Just put the function in the object instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` for this case

```
  sumOfPaymentBalance = accounts.payments.reduce((sum,currentValue)=> 
                          (sum+currentValue.balance),0);
    mainBalance = accounts.reduce(sum,paymentValue=>(sum,paymentValue.balance),0);
    sumOfPaymentBalance += mainBalance;
    console.log(sumOfBalance);
```

Comment: `1` what is the difference between your way and `Jaydip Rakholiya` way? i mean which one has better functionality? `2` and if i want to use your way what would be the code exactly? (based on my function)

Comment: There is no much difference.My suggestion is a different approach to solve it.I have used the `ES6` syntax and `reduce` method.When you want to get a single value after performing a same operation over each array of objects then `reduce` is more relevant and meant for it

Answer (score 0):

I just tried making a more generic type of solution to count a given key which can be nested into as many arrays or objects as you wish.

```
summarize = (obj, sum_key) => {
  var sum = 0;
  for ( key in obj ) {
    if (key == sum_key) {
      sum += obj[key];
    } else if (typeof obj[key] == 'object' && obj[key]) {
      sum += summarize(obj[key]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
};
```

Now you can get the required sum with:

```
summarize(data, 'balance');
```